# Appending a domain to username for automated login using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Hello and thank you in advance for your time.

I am trying to automate a login for a specific site using VBscript. My code works great...up to a point. I execute the script, it opens IE, populates both the username and the password, and then submits. The problem is, after the credentials are submitted, I get an error saying the username and/or password is incorrect. I know 100% both the username and password are in fact correct.

I am quite sure I have located the culprit, however I cannot figure out how I should amend my code to accommodate. A good look at the login screen with firebug revealed a domain was being appended to the username. My code does not reflect this, therefore I get the username/password error after I submit.

Here is my code... and below my code is the JavaScript pulled from the website using firebug:

```
On Error Resume Next 

Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Call objIE.Navigate("https://snvacaid-bwxsp01.megapathvoice.com/Login/")

objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : 

Loop

objIE.Document.loginForm.EnteredUserID.Value = "username"

objIE.Document.all.Password.Value = "password"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    msgbox "Error: " & err.Description

End If

Call objIE.Document.all.loginForm.submit

Set objIE = Nothing
```

JavaScript from website:

```
function submitForm() {
    //append domain to the userId if it is available and not

    //already contained in the userId

    var userId = document.loginForm.EnteredUserID.value;

    var domain = document.loginForm.domain.value;

    document.loginForm.UserID.value = userId;

    if ((userId.indexOf("@") == -1) && (domain != "")){
        document.loginForm.UserID.value = userId + "@" + domain;
    }

    document.loginForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Looks like they are adding the domain name to your username if it ain't present using javascript function . Just providing the username as in the form "username@domain" in your vb script should solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried "domain\userId"?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking so long in informing all that I answered my own question; however, below is the solution I came up with and it does work. Thank you for all the replies.

```
On Error Resume Next 

Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Call objIE.Navigate("https://snvacaid-bwxsp01.megapathvoice.com/Login/")

objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep (100) 

Loop

objIE.Document.loginForm.UserID.Value = "username"

objIE.Document.all.Password.Value = "password"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

msgbox "Error: " & err.Description

End If



Call objIE.Document.all.loginForm.submit
```